# Python Pandas Read Complete String with reference of part of string

Tags: python, pandas

I need the read the complete string with reference of part of the string.

example string Hello_world_10_04_2020_19_00,  reference string we have is Hello_world and I don't know the complete string to search.  How to read the complete string with small part of the information of the string?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the occurence of a substring in a string by using 'substring in string' way.

> Code:

```
string = "Hello_World_welcome"
substring = "Hello_World"
if substring in string:  #checking whether the substring in string
    print(string)  #displays the string having occurence of substring
```

> Output

```
Hello_World_welcome
```

If you want to find strings from the list which having the substring, then follow the below code.

> Code:

```
text_list = ["are you there","Hello_world_welcome","hai","Hello_world_10_04_2020_19_00"]
substring = "Hello_World"
for text in text_list: #iterates through the list
    if substring in text: #checking whether the string contains the substring 'Helllo_World'
        print(text)  #displays the text having occurence of substring
```

> Output:

```
Hello_world_welcome
Hello_world_10_04_2020_19_00
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Hello Rajan, Its worked super... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I have used **Pandas** library as you have requested.

You can find the srings having the substring **"Hello_world"** by using the **str.find()**

Function str.find() returns the lowest index in the string where substring "Hello_world" is found within the slice s[start:end]. If found it returns '0' unless it returns '-1'. Based on that return value we are getting the selected rows from the dataframe.

> Code:

```
import pandas as pd #importing pandas library

#creating sample text list which contains the substring "Hello_world"
text_list = ["are you there","Hello_world_welcome","hai","Hello_world_10_04_2020_19_00"]

#creating dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({"texts":text_list})
print("-------------Data--------------")
print(data)

#specifying subsring "Hello_world" to variabl sub_string
sub_string = "Hello_world"

#finding all the rows having the substring in string contains in the column named 'texts'
new_data = data[data["texts"].str.find(sub_string )==0]

#displaying resulting dataframe
print("\n\n----------Output Data----------")
print(new_data)

#converting all the text string contains the required substring to a list named result_list
result_list = new_data["texts"].tolist()
print("\n\nResulting List: ",result_list)
```

> Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rajan, 
Ur coding is working awesome, I want it in normal form not in DataFrame method.